# Deployed ASP.NET webform application showing old aspx page even after clearing cache

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I have a very strange error with an asp.net webform application which we deployed to a development server. Here are the strange behaviors.

After deploying, and using IE browser, I can see the new webpages with devexpress gridview. On my older code, the gridview rows were autogrouped by one of the columns, which was an error. I added code to trim the column value and it fixed the grid row autogrouping

Now, here is the strange error. When I redeployed again, some of the developers can view the page without any errors but others are seeing the gridview autogrouping. I deleted the client side cache and change the one of the gridview header literal and confirmed the page is the latest code but some of the user are still getting the gridview row autogrouping while some of us are not.

Other than clearing out the IE caching, I am not what else to do.
Any Idea of why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use a different browser, to see if the caching happens in the browser or somewhere else. Did you restart the web application after deploy? Got proxies in between? Got multiple webservers serving this content? Hard to tell without seeing it happen :)

Comment: Had same problem once, had to clear cache on server to get rid of problem.